# Pug (jade) убрать добавляющийся к тегам пробел

Tags: html, gulp, pug

Использую Gulp,webpack и pug(jade). Проблема в том, что в конечный код попадает лишний пробел из-за форматирования его при сборке.

```
label
  each item in items
    span
      if kkk == 2
        =item[1]
      else
        abbr(title='ttttttt3')
          =elem
```

получается что-то типа в .html

```
<label for="ааааа">установить
    <abbr title="включить">ВКЛ/</abbr>
    <abbr title="выключить">ВЫКЛ</abbr>
</label>
```

и выглядит

> установить ВКЛ/ ВЫКЛ

Как убрать пробел после '/', или что изменить, что бы было

> установить ВКЛ/ВЫКЛ

уточнение:

```
+mixin dd['svg', 'sdf sdfsdsd SVG', , , , [['Scalable Vector Graphics', 3]]],

mixin dd(list)
- var words = [];
- var abbr = [];
each item, i in list
//-....
    - var words = [];
    - var abbr = [];
    +e.INPUT(id= it[0])
    +e.LABEL(for=it[0])
        each elem, i in words
            if it[3] != undefined && it[3].indexOf(i + 1) != -1
                +e.SPAN
                    +other(it[5], abbr, i, words.length, elem)
            else
                +other(it[5], abbr, i, words.length, elem)

mixin other(abbrs, abbr, i, wordslength, elem)
    if abbrs != undefined && abbrs.some(elem => (abbr = elem)[1] == (i + 1))
        abbr(title= abbr[0])
            =elem
        else
            =elem
```

По сути нужно как-то заставить

```
<abbr title="включить">ВКЛ/</abbr>
<abbr title="выключить">ВЫКЛ</abbr>
```

быть одной строкой в результирующем dist-коде.

```
<abbr title="включить">ВКЛ/</abbr><abbr title="выключить">ВЫКЛ</abbr>
```

Comment: а можно рабочий вариант, который можно поместить к себе и посмотреть что и как? А то не ясно куда делся span, что за переменные такие items, item[1], elem, kkk. Попробовал накидать тестовый вариант который бы выдавал код как в "получается что-то типа", у меня наоборот не хочет пробелы ставить даже после "установить".

Comment: @MedvedevDev спасибо, добавил свой код в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получил ответ здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/46048130/873481 :

Установить размер шрифта родительского элемента в 0.

Попробовать выключить форматирование кода для Pug `({ pretty: false })`?

Но нашел способ установить `letter-spacing:-10px`, что не искажает форматирование, в отличии от 0го размера шрифта. Также обворачиваю label-слова в div для применения отличных от span стилей.

Answer (score 0):

я использую символ
`&#32;` это то же самое, что печатает пробел

Comment: Автор вопроса дал самоответ, котрый его вполне устроил. Поясните, пожалуйста, прямо в ответе, что даёт ваше решение и чем оно лучше.